# Tabs are coming on different positions in android and ios

Tags: ionic-framework

i create a project using ionic tab example. but in ios the tabs are coming in bottom but in android tabs are coming in top.how the tabs can come in bottom in both the platforms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ionic framework handles platform specific rendering of the layouts. This can be changed by injecting `$ionicConfigProvider` to the `.config` method in your app.js, the configurations can be changed using the methods exposed by this service. To change the tabs position, add the below line inside your `app.config` method
`$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');` Sample

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
}
```

I have removed other stateProvider & urlRouterProvider code from the above method for brevity

More options regarding `$ionicConfigProvider` is available under this link [http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider)

**Note : This fix works for latest version(v1.0.0-beta.14) of Ionic only.**